# Common Application icons from the Internet?

Tags: c++, icons

I am developing my Application in Qt C++.
I tried creating icons in GIMP but it was too much time consuming with no success at all.
So I decided to find out whether there are icon images available for free on the Internet. I found some good ones at iconarchive. But I doubt whether they are legitimate Copyrighted ones by that site.

So my question is where can I find legally free icon images for common functionalities like New, Open, Save, etc. Since my Application is dual licensed i.e. commercial as well as free version, is there any hope of finding anyone distributing their artwork for free?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt has default system icons for Open,Save and ..., you can load them via `QIcon::fromTheme` function which accepts the name of icon as argument. You can see a list of all available icons from the following websites:

[Theme specification materials](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html)

[Name and description of the icons](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html)

For example, I use `QIcon::fromTheme("application-exit")` for my quit button.

Comment: You are very welcome! If you are programming under windows or mac, would you please tell me if the above works correctly? I have only tested this under Linux. (It should, as Qt is cross-platform)

Comment: sure, I would let you know when I am done with my current project.
This may take a while sorry.
But I will definitely get back to you.